# How to set two versions of an onclick event for anchors that establish the src attribute of an iframe to different html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to accomplish is two different version for an onclick event on anchors depending if the device is mobile or table/desktop.

I can accomplished this for one anchor, but not for multiple, as the src attribute for an iframe should be set differently for each anchor.

For example, currently I have anchors as the ones below

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="$('body').toggleClass('sidebar-toggled'); $('.sidebar').toggleClass('toggled');$('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document1.html');">option1</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="$('body').toggleClass('sidebar-toggled'); $('.sidebar').toggleClass('toggled');$('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document2.html');">option2</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="$('body').toggleClass('sidebar-toggled'); $('.sidebar').toggleClass('toggled');$('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document3.html');">option3</a>
```

For viewports smaller than 576 those onclick events should remain as they are, but for bigger viewports to be as

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="$('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document1.html');">option1</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="$('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document2.html');">option2</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="$('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document3.html');">option3</a>
```

I have set an additional class "mobil" for one anchor:

```
<a class="dropdown-item mobil" href="#" onclick="myFunction">option1</a>
```

An a script to set the different onclick behaviors as

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict";
    $(function myFunction(){
        if ($(window).width() <= 576){
                $('.mobil').on('click',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('body').toggleClass('sidebar-toggled'); 
                $('.sidebar').toggleClass('toggled');
                $('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document1.html');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.mobil').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#theFrame').prop('src', 'document1.html');
            });
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

The implementation for one anchor is doing what is expected regardless of a ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick.

But I would like to know how to apply this to the remaining anchors pointing to document2.html and document3.html without code redundancy or a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot about the target attribute. Set anchors as below:

```
<a class="dropdown-item mobil" href="document1.html" target="theFrame">option1</a>
<a class="dropdown-item mobil" href="document2.html" target="theFrame">option2</a>
<a class="dropdown-item mobil" href="document3.html" target="theFrame">option3</a>
```

and the function to:

```
$(function(){
        if ($(window).width() <= 576){
                $('.mobil').on('click',function() {
                $('body').toggleClass('sidebar-toggled'); 
                $('.sidebar').toggleClass('toggled');
            });
        }
});
```